# Getting listFTP with certain filename pre succesors

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

Im am trying to select which files to get from ftp by filenames and dates
The job should pick ftp files with the current date in the filename

"INCOMING.D< yymmdd>

```
INCOMING.D170318
INCOMING.D170319
INCOMING.D170320
```

In my old setup i would do this by Dynamic create a FTP file

```
option confirm off 
option batch abort
option transfer ascii 
open <hostname>
cd  /home/outbox/
lcd \\<localhosthost>\share\incoming
get INCOMING.D170320
exit
```

and execute it with ftp program

Which processes should i use to optain this functionallity in nifi dataflow 
currently i am working with listFTP and FetchFtp processes but i cannot se how i can create the list of files that i want to get.

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the [`ListFTP`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFTP/index.html) processor, you can provide a *File Filter Regex* which will allow you to only retrieve the filenames that match your desired pattern, something like `^INCOMING\.D\d{6}$`.